# how to add a dict as a value to a key in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict that is - `team={ludo:4,monopoly:5}`

How can I form a new dict that has a key called `board_games` with value has another dict which has a key the team dict above which should look like -

```
new_team = { board_games : {junior:{ludo:4,monopoly:5}}}
```

basically I am trying to do something like perlish -

```
new_team['board_games']['junior'] = team
```

Comment: There should be quotes around your keys, right?

Comment: This isn't Javascript. Keys must be quoted. (They'd need to be quoted in bracket notation in Javascript, too.)

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker sorry .. did correction .still does not work. keyerror: 'board_games'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that in the code you want to write tries to access `new_team['board_games']` without first assigning any value to it. `dict` doesn't support that.

If you absolutely insist that you must write `new_team['board_games']['junior'] = team`, then there are a couple of ways:

1) create the key you need:

```
new_team = { 'board_games' : dict() }
new_team['board_games']['junior'] = team
```

or maybe:

```
new_team = dict()
new_team['board_games'] = dict()
new_team['board_games']['junior'] = team
```

or even:

```
new_team = dict();
new_team.setdefault('board_games', dict())
new_team['board_games']['junior'] = team
```

2) use `defaultdict`:

```
import collections
new_team = collections.defaultdict(dict)
new_team['board_games']['junior'] = team
```

Comment: thats wat exactly I am looking for. I try the way perlish things as new to python. one question. what if i need to add more keys to new_team that is - new_team = dict() ;
new_team['board_games'] = dict()    then new_team = dict() ;
new_team['outdoor_games'] = dict()

Comment: @script_kiddie: There are a few different ways of adding keys to an object that already exists. Above I have shown two of them for `dict` and one for `defaultdict`. To find all of them, read the documentation for `dict` or for `defaultdict`. Based on the code in the above comment, I am not certain whether you understand what the line `new_team = dict()` does. If not then you should also look into that.

Comment: Thanks a ton for understanding my question :)

Answer (score 3):

I fail to see the problem:

```
>>> team = {"ludo": 4, "monopoly": 5}
>>> new_team = {"board_games": {"junior": team}}
>>> new_team
{'board_games': {'junior': {'ludo': 4, 'monopoly': 5}}}
```

If you want to construct it dynamically, [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is what you need:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> new_dict = defaultdict(dict)
>>> new_dict['board_games']['junior'] = team
>>> new_dict
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'board_games': {'junior': {'ludo': 4, 'monopoly': 5}}})
```

Comment: I am trying to form the dict dynamically with     new_team['board_games']['junior'] = team

Comment: @script_kiddie: You should put more effort into explaining, what exactly you are trying to achieve. Honestly, I do not understand your question - Python _is_ a dynamic language, so whenever you assign something you do it more-or-less dynamically.